# cannot implicitly convert type void to object

Tags: mvvm

I work with MVVM and i have this error

```
private Student _student;

public void  inserstudent 
{
    set{ __student=_studentService.InsetStudent(_student); }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private Student _student;

public void  inserstudent 
{
    set{ _student=_studentService.InsetStudent(value); }
}
```

Assuming that `_studentService.InsetStudent` returns the student.  Other than that, I could see this going wrong about four different ways.

I think the issue is that you have an extremely tenuous grasp of programming C# :/

Immediately grab a copy of CLR Via C# by Jeffrey Richter and start reading.  Skip the first two chapters, tho.